# Can I use a KAF lens on a modern Pentax DSLR?

Tags: lens, pentax

I have a Pentax K50. Looking at a new lens which is advertised as being for Pentax K<sub>AF</sub> cameras. Will it work on my camera?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Pentax has the longest history of keeping lens compatibility. Any K-mount lens will work on the K-50. The mount is descried as KAF, KAF2, KAF3 which corresponds to come refinements done over the years but they are still compatible. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentax_K-mount) has an article explaining all the differences.

Comment: Furthermore, the newest lens utilizing KAF4 will also work after a firmware update.